# Cant excute command to OSSController API by Postman

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Follow example of Autodesk to create Viewer, this below api return json for jstree show list of buckets, i have few questions

```
...
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/forge/oss/buckets")]
        public async Task<IList<TreeNode>> GetOSSAsync([FromUri]string id)
        {
            IList<TreeNode> nodes = new List<TreeNode>();
            dynamic oauth = await OAuthController.GetInternalAsync();

            if (id == "#") // root
            {
                BucketsApi appBckets = new BucketsApi();
                appBckets.Configuration.AccessToken = oauth.access_token;

                dynamic buckets = await appBckets.GetBucketsAsync("US", 100);
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, dynamic> bucket in new DynamicDictionaryItems(buckets.items))
                {
                    nodes.Add(new TreeNode(bucket.Value.bucketKey, bucket.Value.bucketKey.Replace(ClientId + "-", string.Empty), "bucket", true));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ObjectsApi objects = new ObjectsApi();
                objects.Configuration.AccessToken = oauth.access_token;
                var objectsList = objects.GetObjects(id);
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, dynamic> objInfo in new DynamicDictionaryItems(objectsList.items))
                {
                    nodes.Add(new TreeNode(Base64Encode((string)objInfo.Value.objectId),
                      objInfo.Value.objectKey, "object", false));
                }
            }
            return nodes;
        }
...
```

why i cant get that json by postman? it return "Message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."
And i dont understand what is ([FromUri] string id) is?

```
function prepareAppBucketTree() {
    $('#appBuckets').jstree({
        'core': {
            'themes': { "icons": true },
            'data': {
                "url": '/api/forge/oss/buckets',
                "dataType": "json",
                'multiple': false,
                "data": function (node) {
                    return { "id": node.id };
                }
            }
        },}
```

the function of jstree, i dont see where to transfer that ([FromUri] string id) like a data to GET command. I miss something?

Appreciate any comments.

Paxton.

Comment: `[FromUri]` reads the data it expects from the request uri [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-fromuri). In the example the id is read from node and put into the request url by using the data attribute. If you wanted to make this call in Postman you would have to manually add it: `locahost:4200/api/forge/oss/buckets?id=[bucketid]`

Comment: You need to understand how JSTree works. In this case at each level when you click on the node, you request to get the childrens. So you make a request with a query. This query contains the id of the node. The root level don't have id so you request with '#' and you know this request is for buckets. Then if you have an id, it's for objects ! If you want to make this request in Postman, follow the comment of @SamuelMiddendorp

Comment: thanks both of you guys. the answers's so clearly.